YouTube Revenue data
I have enabled the youtube monetry scopes. But still not able to fetch the data.
I am trying to fetch my youtube revenue data using the OAUTH 2.0, but I am failling to do so.
I have enabled the apis(alaytics, repoting)  added the scopes. but still not getting the result

Doesn't Youtube do help?
